# Cannot dynamically modify external variables in a subroutine in R while use apply on a matix?

Tags: r, variables, apply, dynamically-generated

This problem has already confused me for a couple of days. Let us say that I have two matrices:

```
matrix_a <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, 
                   dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2", "r3"), c("c1", "c2", "c3")))
matrix_b <- matrix(c("r1", "r2", "c1", "c2"), nrow = 2, ncol = 2)
```

I want to dynamically modify `matrix_a` in a function:

```
change_var <- function(x, matrix_a) {
    if(any(rownames(matrix_a) == x[1])  && any(colnames(matrix_a) == x[2])) {
        matrix_a[x[1], x[2]] <- 1
        return (matrix_a)
    }
}
apply(matrix_b, 1, change_var, matrix_a)
```

however, it seems like that this code cannot change the `matrix_a` at all. But my intended result of `matrix_a` should be

```
   c1 c2 c3
r1  1  0  0
r2  0  2  0
r3  0  0  0
```

How could we achieve the goal of dynamically modification of the `matrix_a`? Please provide me a not-for-loop solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Function arguments are passed-by-value, which is why the original `matrix_a` is not being changed.  Also, `apply` probably won't be faster than a well-written for loop.

Comment: I think I have found the right answer right now.

Comment: @Joshua Use the <<- operation

Comment: `<<-` performs a _search_ for the object you're assigning to and assigns to the global environment if the object cannot be found.  You may want to be more explicit and use `assign(..., envir=.GlobalEnv)`.

Comment: How did the result get a `2` in it? Your `change_var` function only assigns `1` to cells? Did you mean to *increase* the cell value?

Answer (score 0):

As you already know, `<<-` or `assign` can be used to modify a "global" variable. `<<-` is very similar to calling `assign` with `inherits=TRUE`.

...but it seems you're trying to create a matrix which counts the number of occurrences of cell coordinates given by matrix_b? That is more efficiently done (without for loops!) with the `table` function. I added a duplicate row in `matrix_b` to show that it works:

```
matrix_a <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 3, 
                   dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2", "r3"), c("c1", "c2", "c3")))
matrix_b <- matrix(c("r1", "r2", "r2", "c1", "c2", "c2"), nrow = 3, ncol = 2)
# Convert matrix_b from 2-d to 1-d indices
row <- match(matrix_b[,1], rownames(matrix_a))
col <- match(matrix_b[,2], colnames(matrix_a))
idx <- row+(col-1)*nrow(matrix_a)
# Then count the number of identical indices using table
matrix_a[sort(unique(idx))] <- table(idx)
```

Which updates `matrix_a` to:

```
   c1 c2 c3
r1  1  0  0
r2  0  2  0
r3  0  0  0
```

...of course, if you only need to put a `1` in there, you don't need to call `table`:

```
row <- match(matrix_b[,1], rownames(matrix_a))
col <- match(matrix_b[,2], colnames(matrix_a))
idx <- row+(col-1)*nrow(matrix_a)
matrix_a[idx] <- 1
```